# If I were to perform a MD5 hash every microsecond from 1-1-1970 how many hash colisions would I have

Tags: hash

I mean with a standard length of 32 you are doomed to have some hash collision, I ask this question just out of curiosity. I havent put a supercomputer or a timemachine just yet.

Comment: 1Mhash/s is pretty slow for todays standards. A single good GPU is more than a thousand times faster than that (9 Ghash/s).

Answer (score 2):

None, assuming you weren't trying to make a collision. MD5 has a length of 128 bits, giving 64-bit resistance to brute-force collision attacks (i.e. you need to hash 2^64 random things to expect a collision). There have only been around 2^40 microseconds since 1/1/1970, so you wouldn't have any collisions if you picked inputs randomly. You'd have to try to get a collision (which is fairly easy to do, but random picking doesn't help)

Comment: Brute-force collisions will occur probabilistically in a manner that makes it very unlikely that there will be one in this time period, but simply saying no collisions is overly simplistic. Birthday paradox calculator at https://lazycackle.com/Probability_of_repeated_event_online_calculator__birthday_problem_.html gives 1.8e-15 which is certainly negligible, but more informative an answer than "none".

Comment: A 128-bit hash does not have "64-bit collision resistance", that doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky thing is not to have two collisions out of the void (even if this must not happen with secure cryptographic hashes, otherwise it is considered not secure anymore).

The tricky thing is to find a collision against a known hash. For instance, be able to produce a different certificate producing the same hash so the signature would remain valid, be able to produce a different .iso image, update package or binary which would produce the same hash so all signatures would remain OK.

At last, regarding your actual question, it all depends on your computing power. Nowadays, using [a proper attack](http://merlot.usc.edu/csac-f06/papers/Wang05a.pdf), researches claim you can find a MD5 collision in a time varying from 15 minutes to 1 hour.

Comment: does computing power factor in if the speed is assumed to be 1/ms?